# Line from lower left to upper right corner of page with metapost

Tags: backgrounds, metapost, dimensions

I have this example where I want to draw a line in the background from corner to opposite corner of the page using  `metapost`, The problem is that the line does not reach both ends, and I cannot figure out what is missing

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\put(0,-\paperheight){%
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
 draw origin -- (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
}
}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer from David Carlisle is relevant.   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591192/15036

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully at your output you may see that there is a mismatch here between a4 (210mm x 297mm) and letter (8.5in x 11in).
Your PDF appears to have a4 paper, but `paperheight` and `paperwidth` are set for letter paper.

Your example works just fine if I explicitly set `a4paper` and add a magic 2pt shift left.

```
% lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\put(-2,-\paperheight){
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
 drawdblarrow (origin --  (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
}
}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

I added the arrow heads just to show the ends of the line.

[image]

But the actual solution is to add the `geometry` package.  One of the useful things that this does is to normalize the PDF paper sizes so that they match the LaTeX paper sizes. It is quite surprising that the standard classes do not do this!

But if you just add `\usepackage{geometry}` your example will work as expected:

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{%
\put(0,-\paperheight){%
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
 draw origin -- (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
}
}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

Compiling this produces:

[image]